# Suddenly forbidden 403 error on some pages

Tags: pages, errors

Suddenly my Wordpress installation is giving 403 error on only some (two) pages. Disabled all plugins (1) and renamed httaccess but error is still there.

Pages was working fine two days ago. Pages a basic articles without custom template.

Any help?

Comment: and are you sure they are published, not limited to logged in users etc?

Comment: Try changing permalinks

Comment: No, pages are public like others pages. Permalinks changed; no effect.
New information. Permalink of one page is www.....tld/contacts. If i create a new page with permalink www.....tld/cont it gives error 403. Is Wordpress installation corrupted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the permissions of files and folders.
All folders should have permission set to `755` and files should have `644` . If permissions are different than specified, please try changing the permissions.

You can easily check and change permissions using filezilla.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Problem solved. It was server related problem.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone has this issue with just a single page on their WordPress installation I found that I had a folder with the same name as the slug for the page.
Delete said folder and no more 403 error.